# how to use production database on local?

Tags: magento

I have downloaded Magento database from the production environment to use on local. Now while installation when I try to use that database . i get caught into an indefinate loop. what change do I have to make in the database to make it work fine on local, so that I can use the content. I am using wamp on local.

Production environment has multiple websites. so every region has it's own website. there are 5 websites. Please suggest something I really need to use the content like cms pages blocks customer groups etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to table cone_config_data

Update these value to be your localhost url:

```
web/secure/base_url //put the unsecure one in this one for the local 
web/unsecure/base_url
```

Change this value to `0`

```
web/seo/use_rewrites
```

Empty the `var` folder.

Comment: I cannot find web/seo/use_rewrites in core_config_data? I am using magneto Enterprise 1.12

Comment: Query the db like this SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%seo%' , but even without this just changing the urls and clearing cache should already get it working. Turning off rewrites generally works better in a local environment.